# Remove dot/double dot from path in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, path

All single dot components of the path must be removed.

For example, "abi/./bune" should be normalized to "abi/bune".

All double dot components of the path must be removed, along with their parent directory. For example, "abi/ba/../bune" should be normalized to "abi/bune".

without using regular expressions. Any idea how to achieve?

Comment: Use a stack. Tokenize the string by "/". Treat ".." as a pop command, ignore ".", and push everything else

Comment: Instantiate an NSMutableArray. Take the path (an NSString *) and split it up into components separated by the "/" character. Iterate through all components. If the component is a "..", then remove the top object from the mutable array. If it is a ".", then continue to the next component. Otherwise, add it to the mutable array. Combine each component with the "/" character.

Comment: what if you have abc/abi/ba/../../bune should that be abc/bune ??

Comment: this cries out for some code golf: An objective-c solution to normalize path with most code possible. Who is up for some NSScanner madness?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Daniel's answer is the correct one. But since there was a discussion in the comments to the question, I decided to provide a code example for @  Rey Gonzales's idea of tokenizing a string and using a stack.

**WARNING:** this code is here for purely educational purposes (because someone asked for it in the comments to the question). In real life stick to the @Daniel's solution.

The code might look like this:

```
-(NSString *)normalizePath:(NSString *)path {
    NSArray *pathComponents = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

    NSMutableArray *stack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:pathComponents.count];

    for (NSString *pathComponent in pathComponents) {
        if ([pathComponent isEqualToString:@".."]) {
            [stack removeLastObject];
        }
        else {
            if (![pathComponent isEqualToString:@"."]) {
                [stack addObject:pathComponent];
            }
        }
    }

    return [stack componentsJoinedByString:@"/"];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved by calling

```
NSString *standardizedPath = [path stringByStandardizingPath];
```

For example:

```
"/usr/bin/./grep"         ->    "/usr/bin/grep"
"/usr/include/objc/.."    ->    "/usr/include"
```

Worth noticing is that this also removes any initial components of `/private` and tries to expand any initial tilde expressions using `stringByExpandingTildeInPath`.

Comment: Good approach - what happened to `/objc/`? Typo?

Comment: @mc01 No, `..` goes up a single directory. So the `..` was removed along with `objc`